# PdfFormField simply does not hide when setting the visibility to HIDDEN

Tags: pdf, itext, itext7

I'm setting the visibility of a PdfFormField to HIDDEN using the `setVisibility()` method with parameter `PdfFormField.HIDDEN`. Still, on flattening it, the field does not hide. Below is the code to do so.

```
File file = new File("path to PDF file");
baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(file.getAbsolutePath()), new PdfWriter("path to flattened PDF file"));

//This function removes all the permissions.
removePdfPermissions();

form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
fields = form.getFormFields();

fields.get("HumanSubjectsText").setVisibility(PdfFormField.HIDDEN);
fields.get("HumanSubjects").setVisibility(PdfFormField.HIDDEN);

form.flattenFields();
pdfDoc.close();
```

Setting the values of the fields to empty string `""` is a workaround, but not the proper way.

The fields `"HumanSubjects"` and `"HumanSubjectsText"` correspond to a checkbox and its correspond text on page 2. (Human Subjects)

[Link to PDF file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HYlvxVJ2RYu4En1KUAf-roaUjqfeA6cM)

Comment: Maybe you are working with a hybrid form containing the form definition using AcroForm technology *as well as* using the XML Forms Architecture (XFA). In that case, changing the visibility of the AcroForm form field won't help because you make the form ambiguous.

Comment: I had the line removed from my code snippet. It was `form.removeXfaForm();`. But it made no difference.

Comment: @Bruno, if it was a hybrid PDF, setting the field to empty should not work.

Comment: You don't merely hide the field, you also flatten the form. **a** in that case setting the value to "" has the same visual effect as a successful hiding would have as there are no AcroForm form fields afterwards anymore. **b** have you tried hiding without flattening? Probably the issue is not with hiding but with flattening respecting the *hidden* flag.

Comment: @mkl, I created a new PDF from the existing one, without flattening it. Still, the field is visible (even though the call to `setVisibility()`. You can verify it too, I've attached the sample PDF to the question. It would be very helpful if the field can be hidden only using only `iText` library.

Comment: At first glance `PdfAcroForm.flattenFields()` appears to ignore flags. @Bruno Probably it should be discussed whether this is a bug or by design; at least it needs to be documented, though, at least as JavaDoc. (I have not tested this, merely looked at the `PdfAcroForm` code, though, so I might have missed something...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields could not be hidden using iText library. In contrast to Bruno's comment, one of the methods from iText library worked well, the `setValue()`. I'm not quite sure why the `setVisibility()` fails.

However, I was able to hide the field using [Master PDF editor](https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/) tool. I've attached a screenshot of this tool, where you can change the visibility for a form field from the `General` tab.

An observation: In the `com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField` some of the constants defined are as follows:

```
public static final int HIDDEN = 1;
public static final int VISIBLE_BUT_DOES_NOT_PRINT = 2;
public static final int HIDDEN_BUT_PRINTABLE = 3;
public static final int VISIBLE = 4;
```

The [Master PDF editor](https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/) also has similar options to hide a field. Please refer to the attached screenshot.

**NOTE**: My requirement was just to simply hide the field. It could be achieved programmatically by using a library like `iText` or with some PDF editor tool.